# Add custom font in php while creating a doc

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am creating a doc file in php. I want to use `Solaimanlipi` font in my `doc`. I have added that font using `font-face`. But it does not show the output properly. I am adding my code. Any help to resolve this issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252">
<style>
@font-face { font-family: Solaimanlipi;
src: E:/xampp/htdocs/Solaimanlipi.ttf; }           
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>বাংলা বাংলা এখানে এখানে এখানে বাংলা বাংলা এখানে এখানে এখানেবাংলা বাংলা এখানে এখানে এখানেবাংলা বাংলা এখানে এখানে এখানে  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't make up syntax. HTML won't read local path fonts. Consider using web fonts.

Comment: Change `E:/xampp/htdocs/Solaimanlipi.ttf` to `http://localhost/Solaimanlipi.ttf`

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks

Comment: serious professional recommendation: it's 2016, don't pretend you're using the almost 20 year old and *incredibly outdated* XHMTL 1.0 doctype (the XHTML equivalent of the equally obsolete HTML 4.01 from 1998). Writing code today? Use *today's formats*, so use HTML5. Especially if you're writing Bengali, which has **nothing** to do with the US English ANSI codepage `Windows-1252`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two changes to desire output.

**Change 1:** Change`charset=Windows-1252"` to `charset=UTF-8"` So your meta code will be

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

**Change 2:** Change `src: E:/xampp/htdocs/Solaimanlipi.ttf;` to `src: url(http://localhost/SolaimanLipi.ttf);`

**Note**:You should use html 5 structure your html document type very old.

So your full code will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: Solaimanlipi;
    src: url(http://localhost/SolaimanLipi.ttf);
}          
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>বাংলা বাংলা এখানে এখানে এখানে বাংলা বাংলা এখানে এখানে এখানেবাংলা বাংলা এখানে এখানে এখানেবাংলা বাংলা এখানে এখানে এখানে  </p>
</body>
</html>
```